# Remote Access RPi 3 via RPi 0 ...?

Tags: pi-zero, gui, xorg

**Is it possible to remote view a Raspberry Pi 3 with a Raspberry Pi Zero?**

I'm looking for a simple solution to switch to a Full GUI of a remotely accessed Raspi-3 by simply swapping the Input Channel on my Monitor.

My idea would be to have a windows Machine on HDMI 1 and a raspberry pi 0 with network access on HDMI 2.

LAN Access could be established via a Micro-USB-Dongle. This would enable me to have a small-form-factor plug&play option to access a raspberry sitting somewhere else in the building. 
Connection could be tied to MAC of the Raspberry Pi 3 or else, not sure on that point yet.

The Raspberry Pi 0 should only serve as an X-Server for all of the RaspberryPi 3's GUI.

Here's a graphical Overview of the Setup:

[image: Graphical Overview]

---

Mouse+Keyboard support could be realized via Teamviewer session onto the Raspberry Pi Zero, but that kinda circumvents the original plan.

**Can I use a Raspberry Pi Zero and turn it into a KVM Switch?**

Comment: Ok... The solution is unpractical and I might as well be fine with remote software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use VNC to remote-control your RPi's from your Windows computer. Otherwise you will have to have a KVM-switch connected between your computers (Windows + RPi) and the monitor in order to get full mouse- and keyboard access.

Comment: Well, you're right. But what if I can't install on the system I'm working on? KVM switches are pretty expensive too.. But I suppose it would also be mandatory in my idea, didn't really plan ahead on the keyboard/mouse part...

Comment: So, I've changed the original question a little bit. I indeed am looking for something similar to a KVM Switch, only that I'm not directly accessing the RPi 3, since it's sitting somewhere far off.